# How do I stop github from pushing all of my recent projects?

Tags: git, github

When I push from a particular project folder, my github posts several of my most recently pushed projects along with it. It does not post every project I have ever pushed to github, but it reposts several of the projects that I pushed in the past week. Therefore, my folders contain all of this stuff that is not relevant to the repository.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? I searched through stack overflow and could not find a solution to this.

Thanks!

M

Comment: Well, I'd like to ask if the changes in the different folders that git pushes to github are actually parts of the same commits?

Comment: If they are, then that's anavoidable. git (and therefore github) doesn't work on folder level, it works on commit tree level. That is a given commit with the complete file tree _and_ the complete parent graph when pushed to a server is sent completely, w/o exclusions.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. How, then, do you remove the parent graph? I always push to a different origin name. (i.e. git remote add someName). When I push to the origin, I am given a fatal error that the origin already exists. I used to just be able to add one project at a time and am not sure what changed.

Comment: Hmm, how do I remove parent graph? I can't for any particular commit. The fact is a given commit is a set of properties. One of the properties is its commit message, another - author (and committer too), the third one is the complete file tree attached to the commit, and finally the list of parent(s). If you change _anything_ in the list, you'll get a _different_ commit, with different SHA1 etc. Can you describe your needs more completely?

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you mean by different 'projects' that get pushed along with your current project? Are you talking about subdirectories in your main working directory? Where in your directory tree is your git directory located?

Comment: Addendum: to me it sounds like you want separate repos for each of your project directories, but you (accidentally?) ```git init```'d their parent directory and now you always push all of its contents, i.e. all individual project (sub)directories.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. But I am not sure how to reset it. The weird thing is that it pushes my entire Visual Studio 2015 folder and Projects folder, but it does not push everything within those folders (i.e. there are about 100 projects in my Projects folder, but it will only push the five most recent that I've pushed to github).